# HDD spin down time is not working after sleep

Tags: hard-drive, suspend, spindown

I have two hard drives - ssd and hdd. I don't use hdd a lot, so I have set hdd spin down time for 5 minutes (in Disks app). And it's working quite fine if Ubuntu was started from completely turned off state, however when I start my PC from suspend mode, hdd never stops spinning until I do it manually (then it remains silent). What can cause this problem?

Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: I have the same issue with Ubuntu 16.04. I have a `lightdm`.

Answer (score 3):

Problem also exist on my desktop with 16.04. After some research I realized that I can force HDD to go sleep by `hdparm -Y` , but `hdparm -S` doesn't work.

My solution is:

1. Disable spin down time in `gnome-disk-utility` and other tools like
   `hdparm.conf`
2. Install [hd-idle](http://hd-idle.sourceforge.net). You can use [this](http://blog.is-a-geek.org/festplatten-in-den-standby-modus-versetzen-unter-ubuntu-desktopserver-mit-hd-idle) link for instructions on install and configure
3. Create new file at `/lib/systemd/system-sleep` e.g. `hdidle` with executable bit
4. Add following code:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   if [ "$2" = "suspend" ] || [ "$2" = "hybrid-sleep" ]; then
       case "$1" in
           post) hd-idle -i 0 -a sdb -i 60 -a sdc -i 60 ;;
       esac
   fi
   ```

This will spin down the disk after 60s (edit it as you need). Change `sdb` and `sdc` accordingly.

Comment: This seems to provide relevant information, but not useful as an answer. Consider to include essential steps and explain how to set up the solution. In particular, explain whether "disable spin down time in gnome-disk-utility" and "install hd-idle" are two different solutions or must be done together.

Comment: Thanks for an advice. Edited the post since previously provided info was not complete/not work as expected. Hope it's more comprehensive now.